# How do I retrieve the Picasa id/URL of an image from the gallery

Tags: android, url, gallery, android-intent, picasa

I have an activity that retrieves images from the device's gallery and uploads to a service. Now, for optimisation purposes, I would like to avoid uploading images that are on Picasa an just store their ID or URL for later retrieval.

So my question is, how do I retrieve that information. My intent code is pasted below and retrieves the URI of the image.

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
```

I tried to look for the PICASA_ID (MediaStore.Images.Media.PICASA_ID), but by using the method above, it returns null. Any ideas?

Comment: Nobody? Can anyone give me some pointers about how I can retrieve the PICASA_ID from a picture showing on the gallery in albums marked with the Picasa logo? Is that even possible?

Comment: By picasa do you mean: http://picasa.google.com/ ?

Comment: Well, not quite. The Android default image gallery displays albums from picasa connected to your google account.

Comment: The only solution I have found that actually works and covers different Android versions, picasa thumbnails and local files is:
http://dimitar.me/how-to-get-picasa-images-using-the-image-picker-on-android-devices-running-any-os-version/

Answer (score 0):

- Launch an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent instead of an `ACTION_PICK`
- Provide a `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra with an `URI` to a temporary file.

---

Add this to your ***calling activity***:

```
File yourFile;
```

Now use this ***code to get Intent***:

```
yourFile = getFileStreamPath("yourTempFile");
yourFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
galleryIntent .setType("image/*");
galleryIntent .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(yourFile));
galleryIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.name());
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
```

MAKE SURE THAT `yourFile` is created

Also in your ***calling activity***

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode){
    case GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST:
        File file = null;
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        if (imageUri == null || imageUri.toString().length() == 0) {
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(mTempFile);
            file = mTempFile;
            //this is the file you need! Check it
        }
        //if the file did not work we try alternative method
        if (file == null) {
            if (requestCode == 101 && data != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                //check this string to extract picasa id
            }
        }
    break;
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null)
    {
        int index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Comment: Hm, I had figured the first part out, but that is not what i am trying to do. I do not want to download the file from picasa locally, that is a very expensive bandwidth and resource heavy operation. I just need the picasa Id, so I can attach that to my data. I will try the second piece (if file == null) and if that works, than I have an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I looked at the answer and it looks like my question has not been understood. What I am trying to do is avoid downloading the picture from picasa in any way. Therefore storing it locally as a temp file does not do it. I am asking if there is any way to retrieve any information about that image (id, picasa url etc.) from the built in gallery/album.

Comment: Also, the solution above does not work, not on my N1. The image cannot be stored on the card, I geterrors and a null path: 08-15 18:35:03.747: ERROR/(11427): Not JPEG: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1313433294232.jpg
08-15 18:35:03.797: ERROR/(11427): Not JPEG: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1313433294232.jpg
08-15 18:35:03.847: ERROR/PicasaAPI(11427): getAlbums: unexpected status code 403 data: java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream@40554d48. Secondly, if I just do the file == null part, I get a path that contains a long number that is an ad-hoc UID but not connected to any picasa identification.

Comment: wasnt here: try to log.v("",imageUri) .. see what data is there!

Comment: Here's what I get: 08-16 00:33:28.033: ERROR/CropImage(12825): Cannot save to uri file:///data/data/my.app.package/files/yourTempFile
08-16 00:33:28.113: WARN/MY LOG::URI(12896): file:///data/data/my.app.package/files/yourTempFile

Comment: if (imageUri == null || imageUri.toString().length() == 0) {
    log.v("sherif",imageUri);
}

Comment: this displays either "null" or "". not sure what the point is.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dir =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyImages");
        dir.mkdir();
        filename = ("Image_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".poc");
    }

protected Uri getTempFile()
    {
        File file = new File(dir,filename);
        muri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        return muri;
     } 


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add("Pick Image");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         openOptionsChooseDialog();
         return true;
    }

 private void openOptionsChooseDialog()
    {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AppActivity.this).setTitle("Select Image").setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempFile());
                        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
 }

            });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
  }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode)
        {
case SELECT_PICTURE : if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
                  filepath = muri.getPath();
                  Toast.makeText(this, filepath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //can do bla bla bla...
            }
```

I have used the same approach and it woks.Hope It could help u too..

Comment: This is not answering my question. You are downloading the file locally, under /MyFiles, with a timestamp in the file name but are not retrieving any picasa identification information. I do not want to download the file locally, I just need the picasa url of the corresponding file, so I can store it and use it later. This needs to work when the user is offline, so for testing purposes, in airplane mode.