# How do I retrieve a picasa photo from a built-in gallery?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I want to retrieve the photos from built-in Android gallery calling `ACTION_PICK` Intent.
I have a problem with Picasa's images.
I have used the code to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978906/how-do-i-retrieve-the-picasa-id-url-of-an-image-from-the-gallery), but it don't work (the File object don't exist).
Any idea, please.

Answer (score 5):

ACTIVITYRESULT_CHOOSEPICTURE is the int you use when calling startActivity(intent, requestCode);

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == ACTIVITYRESULT_CHOOSEPICTURE) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    final InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    is.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, it works fine, even when the picture comes from picasa. Remember to do this code on a thread, since it may download content from the net.

Answer (score 0):

The code works if is insert this instruction:

```
 intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

- Launch an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent instead of an `ACTION`_PICK
- Provide a `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra with an URI to a temporary file.

Add this to your **calling activity:**

> File yourFile;

Now use this `code to get Intent`:

```
yourFile = getFileStreamPath("yourTempFile");
yourFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
galleryIntent .setType("image/*");
galleryIntent .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(yourFile));
galleryIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.name());
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
```

MAKE SURE THAT `yourFile` is created

Also in your **calling activity**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode){
    case GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST:
        File file = null;
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        if (imageUri == null || imageUri.toString().length() == 0) {
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(mTempFile);
            file = mTempFile;
            //this is the file you need! Check it
        }
        //if the file did not work we try alternative method
        if (file == null) {
            if (requestCode == 101 && data != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                //check this string to extract picasa id
            }
        }
    break;
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null)
    {
        int index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Comment: The mTempFile file is ever empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
final Uri tempUri = data.getData();
                    Uri imageUri = null;
                    final InputStream imageStream;
                    try {
                        imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(tempUri);
                        Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        imageUri = getImageUri(getActivity(), selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```